# TensorFlow - InvalidArgumentError: you must feed a value for placeholder

Tags: python, tensorflow

**Edit:** I've identified the following line in particular as the source of the error,

```
unstacked_observation_outputs = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.xw_plus_b(unstacked_observation_outputs[
            tf.reduce_max(length(observation_history)).eval(session = self.sess) - 1], 
                weights['second_observation'], biases['second_observation']))
```

In particular, applying `.eval()` in `tf.reduce_max(length(observation_history)).eval(session = self.sess) - 1` is the problem.

I have two very similar classes. One called Actor() and the other Critic(). When I instantiate an actor object as follows:

```
class Actor(object):

def __init__(self, sess, observation_dimension, action_dimension, learning_rate, tau):

    self.sess = sess
    self.observation_dimension = observation_dimension
    self.action_dimension = action_dimension
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.tau = tau
    self.lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_hidden_units)

    with tf.variable_scope('lstm') as scope:
        self.observation_history, self.action_history = self.depthless_lstm()
        self.network_parameters = tf.trainable_variables()
        scope.reuse_variables()
        self.target_observation_history, self.target_action_history = self.depthless_lstm()
        self.target_network_parameters = tf.trainable_variables()[len(self.network_parameters):]

    def depthless_lstm(self):
        state = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3600, self.observation_dimension])

        weights = {
        '0': tf.get_variable('weights_0', [lstm_hidden_units, hidden_units_01], initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        '1': tf.get_variable('weights_1', [hidden_units_01, 1], initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
        }
        biases = {
        '0': tf.get_variable('biases_0', [hidden_units_01], initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        '1': tf.get_variable('biases_1', [1], initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
        }

        lstm_outputs, learned_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(self.lstm_cell, state, dtype = tf.float32)

        unstacked_lstm_outputs = tf.unstack(lstm_outputs, axis = 1)

        list_of_hidden_01_outputs = [tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.xw_plus_b(matrix, weights['0'], biases['0'])) 
        for matrix in unstacked_lstm_outputs]

        actions = [tf.nn.softmax(tf.nn.xw_plus_b(matrix, weights['1'], biases['1'])) 
        for matrix in list_of_hidden_01_outputs]

        actions = [actions[n] for n in range(len(actions)) if (n % frequency) == 1]

        return state, actions

actor = Actor(sess, observation_dimension, action_dimension, learning_rate, tau)
```

I don't receive any error. However, when I instantiate a critic object as follows:

```
class Critic(object):

def __init__(self, sess, observation_dimension, action_dimension, learning_rate, tau, 
    model, number_actor_variables):

    self.sess = sess
    self.observation_dimension = observation_dimension
    self.action_dimension = action_dimension
    self.learning_rate = learning_rate
    self.tau = tau

    self.lstm_observation_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(lstm_observation_units)

    with tf.variable_scope('next_lstm') as scope:
        self.observation_history, self.action, self.critique = self.depthless_lstm_critic()
        self.network_parameters = tf.trainable_variables()[number_actor_variables:]
        scope.reuse_variables()
        self.target_observation_history, self.target_action, self.target_critique = self.depthless_lstm_critic()
        self.target_network_parameters = tf.trainable_variables()[(len(self.network_parameters) 
            + number_actor_variables):]

    def depthless_lstm_critic(self):
        observation_history = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3600, self.observation_dimension])
        action = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, self.action_dimension])

        weights = {
        'first_observation': tf.get_variable('first_observation', [self.observation_dimension, observation_hidden_units01], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        'first_action': tf.get_variable('first_action', [self.action_dimension, action_hidden_units01], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        'second_observation': tf.get_variable('second_observation', [lstm_observation_units, observation_hidden_units02], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        'second_action': tf.get_variable('second_action', [action_hidden_units01, action_hidden_units02], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        'combined_observation': tf.get_variable('combined_observation', [observation_hidden_units02, combined_units], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        'combined_action': tf.get_variable('combined_action', [action_hidden_units02, combined_units], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        'final': tf.get_variable('final', [combined_units, 1], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
        }
        biases = {
        'first_observation': tf.get_variable('_first_observation', [observation_hidden_units01], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        'first_action': tf.get_variable('_first_action', [action_hidden_units01], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        'second_observation': tf.get_variable('_second_observation', [observation_hidden_units02], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        'second_action': tf.get_variable('_second_action', [action_hidden_units01], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        'combined': tf.get_variable('_combined', [combined_units], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer()),
        'final': tf.get_variable('_final', [1], 
        initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer())
        }

        unstacked_observation_history = tf.unstack(observation_history, axis = 1)

        unstacked_observation_history = [tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.xw_plus_b(vector, 
        weights['first_observation'], biases['first_observation'])) 
            for vector in unstacked_observation_history]

        learned_action = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.xw_plus_b(action, weights['first_action'], biases['first_action']))

        stacked_observation_history = tf.stack(unstacked_observation_history, axis = 1)

        lstm_observation_outputs, observation_states = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(self.lstm_observation_cell, 
        stacked_observation_history, dtype = tf.float32, 
            sequence_length = length(stacked_observation_history))

        unstacked_observation_outputs = tf.unstack(lstm_observation_outputs, axis = 1)

        unstacked_observation_outputs = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.xw_plus_b(unstacked_observation_outputs[
            tf.reduce_max(length(observation_history)).eval(session = self.sess) - 1], 
                weights['second_observation'], biases['second_observation']))

        learned_action = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.xw_plus_b(learned_action, weights['second_action'], 
        biases['second_action']))

        combined_results = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(weights['combined_observation'], 
        unstacked_observation_outputs) + tf.nn.xw_plus_b(learned_action, weights['combined_action'], 
            biases['combined']))

        critique = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(combined_results, weights['final'], biases['final'])

        return observation_history, action, critique

critic = Critic(sess, observation_dimension, action_dimension, learning_rate, tau, 
    model, number_actor_variables)
```

I get the following error message:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'next_lstm/Placeholder' with dtype float
[[Node: next_lstm/Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

and traceback

```
Caused by op 'next_lstm/Placeholder', defined at:
File "test_critic.py", line 89, in <module>
model, number_actor_variables)
File "test_critic.py", line 15, in __init__
self.observation_history, self.action, self.critique = 
self.depthless_lstm_critic()
File "test_critic.py", line 23, in depthless_lstm_critic
observation_history = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 3600, 
self.observation_dimension])
```

The traceback indicates the issue is with the placeholder `observation_history`. But that part of the code seems to be identical to what I wrote for the Actor() class which produces no error message.

Comment: Could some one tell me why this question is being marked down so I can change how I ask questions in the future?

Comment: Because, your code is not right formatted, how could you define `__init__` for a class without indent? And, you post too much code, it seems you didn't get the critical point.

Comment: @Sraw Oh, thanks for noticing that. The indentation is correct in my code but it became messed up when I copied it over. I'll post less code next time. I thought people would want to see all of it but I can see how it's hard to read through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`observation_history` is a placeholder, that means it is an empty node in the graph when building graph and waiting for some actual values. So you need to pass some values to this placeholder.

```
Tensor.eval({self.placeholderA : someValueA, self.placeholderB : someValueB ...}, self.sess)
```

In your case, you need to pass some actual values to `observation_history`.